# Changing color on BoundingRegion when not a Graphics primitive or directive

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

If we take the documentation example for `BoundingRegion` and change `"MinDisk"` to `"MinConvexPolygon"` it no longer works:

```
pts = {{3, 10}, {6, 3}, {10, 2}, {2, 8}, {3, 3}};
BoundingRegion[pts, "MinConvexPolygon"]
Graphics[{{Yellow, %}, Point[pts]}, ImageSize -> Tiny]
```

gives the error:

```
"BoundaryMeshRegion is not a Graphics primitive or directive".
```

`BoundingRegion[pts, "MinConvexPolygon"]` does give a working Graphics object that I can use in plots. But how do I change the color in this case?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`BoundaryMeshRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryMeshRegion) to change the mesh cell styles:

```
BoundaryMeshRegion[
    BoundingRegion[pts, "MinConvexPolygon"],
    MeshCellStyle -> {2 -> Orange}
]
```

[image]

In Mathematica 12 [`BoundaryMeshRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryMeshRegion) is supported as a [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) primitive:

```
pts={{3,10},{6,3},{10,2},{2,8},{3,3}};
BoundingRegion[pts,"MinConvexPolygon"]
Graphics[{{Yellow,%},Point[pts]},ImageSize->Tiny]
```

[image]